# OBIEE - How to use result in column/row as part or query in another column?

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

In my Oracle BI 11g, Criteria Tab, I can select columns for eg 'Name' and 'Country'. These two is in the same Subject Area.

From a different Subject Area, I can Select column 'Adress'. But this column for 'Adress' won't work with the columns present in my analysis, and comes out blank.

So, what I need is help to edit the SQL written in column 'Adress' in such a way that it can pick up the names already present in column 'Name' and use this to find adresses for each row.

Is this possible? And how would such a SQL look like, given my column names (missing subject area names can I put into the code myself).

Comment: Show the code that you have tried and then it will be possible to help correct it

Comment: Why are you asking for SQL code?! OBI works with models. It's declarative. It's not Toad or SQL Developer

Comment: The Edit Column Formula part looks like:

Name:
"Navn (A felles)"."Navn"

Adress:
"Adresse bolig (P Felles)"."Bolig adresse"

I don't have any suggestions on my own, because I don't know how to write it.
And I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge. This is OBI, but when I see that I can use commands as "CASE" and "COUNT", I'm automaticly thinking of SQL... Sorry. :)

Comment: Have you already just googled "obiee filter based on another analysis"?

Comment: All of this is inside the same analysis. As far as I know, to use Filter + ... is results from another analysis, I have to point it to another analysis..?